# create custom json array from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, rest

I have following table in mysql.
    1)User

```
userid    username    college
1         robert      sarauniversity
2         albert      oxford

2)UserDetails
userid     subjectid
1          1
1          2
2          3
1          4
2          1

3)subjectdetails
subjectid  subjectname          subjectteacher
1          basic science        pro. vengaskar
2          advance mathematics  pro. richard
3          history              pro. michale
4          geography            pro. renuka
```

I need following data in json

```
  [  
  {
   id:1
   username:robert      
   subjects:[
   {
       subjectname:pro. geography            ,
       subject teacher:algebra

   },
  {
       subjectname:pro. vengaskar,
       subject teacher:pro. renuka
  }
  ]
  },
  {
   id:2
   username:albert      
   subjects:[
   {
       subjectname:history                          ,
       subject teacher: pro. michale

   },
  {
       subjectname:basic science,
       subject teacher: pro. vengaskar

  }
  ]
  }
  }
```

I have developed json rest api several times but this time it is json array with object which have json array.
I ma confused how to iterate content and get final desired json.
I am not pasting php code as nothing going to help me.
so sad it took my two days but still at beginning...

Comment: What is your problem?!!

Comment: What is `id:1` in your JSON Format ?

Comment: Obviously this is the user id

Answer (score 1):

With a query like this get the result

```
SELECT A.userid,A.username, C.subjectname,C.subjectteacher FROM `A` AS users INNER JOIN `UserDetails` AS B on A.userid = b.userid INNER JOIN `subjectdetails` AS C on C.subjectid = B.subjectid
```

And then manipulate result in the below format in your loop

```
$arr = array (
        array (
                "id" => "1",
                "username" => "Robert",
                "subjects" => array (
                        array (
                                "subjectname" => "pro. geography",
                                "subject teacher" => "algebra" 
                        ) 
                ) 
        ) 
);

echo json_encode ( $arr );
```

OutPut

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "username": "Robert",
        "subjects": [
            {
                "subjectname": "pro. geography",
                "subject teacher": "algebra"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi Noor,its dynamic from db field so need php loop structure for that.I do not think it will be solved within one loop.I am hang up with loop.

Comment: actually I have simplified my real requirement.real code is tough to understand.

Comment: real code have business logic like audit table,checklist realted to audit and so on.So I have simplified in terms of easy example else real sql query is too large.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT @pv := usr.userid, CONCAT(  "[", CONVERT( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  "{\"id\":", usr.userid,  ", \"subjects\":", (
SELECT CONCAT(  "[", CONVERT( GROUP_CONCAT(  "{\"id\":", subjectid,  ", \"subjectname\":\"", subjectname,  "\"}" ) 
USING utf8 ) ,  "]" ) 
FROM subjectdetails
WHERE subjectid
IN (
SELECT subjectid
FROM UserDetails
WHERE userid = @pv)
),  ", \"username\":\"", usr.username,  "\"}" ) 
USING utf8 ) ,  "]" ) AS jsn
FROM User usr
JOIN UserDetails det ON det.userid = usr.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN subjectdetails sub ON sub.subjectid = det.subjectid
```

Output:

```
ID  JSN
1   [{"id":1, "subjects":[{"id":1, "subjectname":"basic science"},{"id":2, "subjectname":"advance mathematics"},{"id":4, "subjectname":"geography"}], "username":"robert"},{"id":2, "subjects":[{"id":1, "subjectname":"basic science"},{"id":2, "subjectname":"advance mathematics"},{"id":4, "subjectname":"geography"}], "username":"albert"}]
```

The JSN column having the structure

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subjects": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subjectname": "basic science"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "subjectname": "advance mathematics"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "subjectname": "geography"
            }
        ],
        "username": "robert"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "subjects": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subjectname": "basic science"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "subjectname": "advance mathematics"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "subjectname": "geography"
            }
        ],
        "username": "albert"
    }
]
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/635e4/2)

Note: The JSON structure in your question is not a valid one. Use [jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) to generate valid json.